# Upvote and Downvote Design in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using Java in Google App Engine.

The scenario is that users can upvote and downvote an Article object. Users can upvote only once per article. What is the best implementation on this?

Thanks

Comment: create a vote table with column of article and user and vote type (up/down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Vote entity that its key is the user id and the article id. This way you can get the user vote without a query and you don't need a transaction to create a user vote.

Comment: composite key is not supported in appengine

Comment: @JRGalia use a string that have both elements